# How to open multiple MP3 files with batch or vbs, just like Ctrl+A Enter

Tags: batch-file

Just like the title suggests, I want to make a batch or vbs script file that will start playing music from my music folder. I can't make playlist because I'm updating this folder very often, and I don't want to keep updating the playlist.

I know that I can just make shortcut to this folder and press `ctrl+a` and `enter`, but I'm lazy. So is there any possibility to do this?

Oh and this:`for %%i in (*.mp3) do start %%i` is not working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

### AUTO-OPEN MP3 FILES WITH WINDOWS MEDIA PLAYER TO PLAY

> How to open multiple MP3 files with batch or vbs, just like Ctrl+A Enter

*(There are two scripted solutions below (`batch` and `VB script`) to open all `MP3` files in a single folder with `Windows Media Player` which will play one song after the other without you needing to do manually from `WMP` after each song finishes or creating a playlist.)*

*(This emulates going to a folder where ONLY `MP3` files are located, doing a **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>** and then pressing **<kbd>Enter</kbd>** or selecting `Open` which iniates `Windows Media Player` to open those selected `MP3` files and play one after the other.)*

*(In this case the `MP3` file folder (`Music`) had additional `MP3` files added frequently and it was just as easy to do a **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>** and then press **<kbd>Enter</kbd>** to get `WMP` to open and play one-by-one.)*

**Essentially these are ways to play all `MP3` files in a folder without creating and playlist and without needing to do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> manually.**

---

### VBS SCRIPT SOLUTION

The line that is `WshShell.Run "D:\Test\TestMP3Only"` will need to be updated to point to the folder location where you complete the **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>** and then press **<kbd>Enter</kbd>** when you do that manually.

The expectation here is that this folder location will only contain MP3 files only.  Otherwise other files will open in this folder location as well.

Save this to a text file named `<something>.vbs` and then click it to launch. I tested and this works and the next song plays after the one playing is finished with native Windows Media Player on Windows.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "D:\Test\TestMP3Only"
Wscript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "^a"
Wscript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

---

### BATCH SCRIPT SOLUTION

The line that is `SET MP3Folder=D:\Test\TestMP3Only` will need to be updated to point to the folder location where you complete the **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>** and then press **<kbd>Enter</kbd>** when you do that manually.

The expectation here is that this folder location will only contain MP3 files only.  Otherwise other files will open in this folder location as well.

Save this to a text file named `<something>.cmd` and then click it to launch. I tested and this works and the next song plays after the one playing is finished with native Windows Media Player on Windows.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET MP3Folder=D:\Test\TestMP3Only
SET TempVBSFile=%tmp%\~tmpMP3Temp.vbs

:VBSDynamicBuild
IF EXIST "%TempVBSFile%" DEL /F /Q "%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.Run "%MP3Folder%"                           >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "^a"                               >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO Wscript.Sleep 500                                    >>"%TempVBSFile%"
ECHO WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"                          >>"%TempVBSFile%"

CSCRIPT //nologo "%TempVBSFile%"
GOTO EOF
```

Comment: no... It waits, but it starts playing first track, and then it looks like it starting the rest, but nothing is happening. I mean this tracks are not adding to music player, and not starts in this...  I thinkig is there maybe a application that when is runnig it starts all files in folder, because if yes i can just run this app via bat or vbs easy (I want do this in autostart)

Comment: -1  you should at least test it so you see it works in at least one media player

Comment: Well for tests i changed the default mp3 player to WIndows media player, and this work else than when that was AIMP, but still not correct. It isn't make something like ctrl+a, it just select file starting it, wait 1-2 sec, select second, start it and do this to last song.

Comment: vivent , in his first comment (not sure what he is saying now), said it didn't work, so either you should have tested it and found it does work and tell him it does and try to see why there's a difference between your test and his. Or, you test it and find it doesn't work and change your answer.  But posting an answer that you haven't tested and that the OP says doesn't work, is not a good answer

Comment: You can just answer their question as it is. If they missed out some specifics like what OS, or what program they are using for their music, then you won't be wrong if you answer for a currently used Windows OS, and a native media player like Windows Media Player.  In their question they wrote mp3 so answer for mp3.  Suppose you don't know the answer for any OS or any media player, then asking them won't help much. And if you know for two different OSs or media playing programs, then no harm in answering for both. It makes for an even more comprehensive answer.

Comment: also, It says batch file so it'd be Windows, and trying to distinguish one version of windows from another, without giving any reason why there'd be a difference in relation to the answer, is just muddying the water and making an answer less applicable to more people

Comment: It's not a waste of time to post a comment n somebody else posts an answer.Don't worry so much about missing out on more rep.It takes much less time to post a comment than to post an answer.So u'll have spent more time if u post an answer than2post a comment.If somebody posts an answer then they've spent more time than u.And if they post a problematic answer eg untested, then they may/may not get accepted but it was higher risk,and they may get downvoted too.If u just care about making quality contributions,then whether it's a short comment,or a tested answer,they're not equal,but both r fine.